# How to print a fraction in latex form?

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have a fraction and I want to print the latex form of it.
The fraction is like this for n == 3:
[image]

How can I print the latex for this fraction using divide and conquer:
`1+\frac{2+\frac{4}{5}}{3+\frac{6}{7}}`

And for n == 4 the fraction is:
[image]

And the result is:
`1+\frac{2+\frac{4+\frac{8}{9}}{5+\frac{10}{11}}}{3+\frac{6+\frac{12}{13}}{7+\frac{14}{15}}}`

Comment: What is the algorithm for coming up with those fractions? I think it could probably done greedily.

Comment: @Neil I'm sorry. But it's a homework and I have to solve it with divide and conquer.

Comment: Sounds like you need a recurrence relation between `a_1` and `a_{2top}`, `a_{2bottom}` that stops after `n`, starting with 1.

Comment: Like `2 a_1 = a_{2top}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
I've tried to solve the problem by using divide and conquer. My solution has two parameters, start and step. Start is the value that is printed at the first step. and step is the value that shows the number of fractions.
If step = 1, then I print just the value of start. Otherwise for each step the numerator of the fraction is 2*start and for denominator the value is 2*start+1.
Here is the code of my solution.

```
def generate_fraction(start : int, step : int):
  result = ""
  if step == 1:
    result = str(start)
  else:
    result = str(start) + '+\\frac{'+ generate_fraction(2*start, step-1) + '}{' + generate_fraction(2*start + 1, step-1) + '}'
  return result

# Main Program ...
step = int(input())
start = 1
print(generate_fraction(start, step))
```